# Can't get select radio button on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, ejs

I'm having problems getting the radio button value when the form is submitted. I thought that when the form is submitted it would get the final selection that user made but it appears it doesn't recognize which one is selected.

On initial load: This is inside my form

```
<div id="question1">
  <label> Do you shop mostly on-line or at physical stores? </label>
    <div class="radioButtons">
      <span>
       Mostly on-line stores
       <input name="question1" value="on-line" type="radio">
      </span>
      <span>
        mostly physical stores
        <input name="question1" value="physical" type="radio">
      </span>
      <span>
        About both equaly
        <input name="question1" value="both" type="radio">
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

in my submit handler

```
    $(".aboutmeQuestions").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var values = {};
        var $inputs = $(".aboutmeQuestions :input").not(":submit");

        $inputs.each(function(){
            values[this.name] = {answer : $(this).val()};
        });
        //I thought the above would get the radio buttons but I think it got the last choice as the selected one no matter what was chosen. so I tried below because I thought that the checked attribute would change automatically.
        $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
            console.log("this ",this);
            if($(this).attr("checked")){
                values[this.name] = {answer : $(this).val()};
            }

        })
```

In my EJS:

```
    <div id="question1">
           <label> <%=aboutUser.question1.question%> </label>
           <div class = "radioButtons">
                <span>Mostly on-line stores <input type="radio" name="<%=aboutUser.question1.name%>" value="on-line" <% if(aboutUser.question1.answer == "on-line"){%> checked  <%}%>> </span>
                <span>mostly physical stores <input type="radio" name="<%=aboutUser.question1.name%>" value="physical" <% if(aboutUser.question1.answer == "physical"){%> checked <%}%>> </span>
                <span> About both equaly <input type="radio" name="<%=aboutUser.question1.name%>" value="both" <% if(aboutUser.question1.answer == "both"){%> checked  <%}%> ></span>
            </div>

    </div>
```

I tested it out. After clicking on nothing and pressing the submit button I get for `values` object, `question5[answer]: maybe"` `question1[answer]: "both"` that should of been equal to nothing. It is always like that no matter what I click. I don't like that pleas help me fix it. I didn't think I have to use a change method.

Ps I save this data to DB and the inputs should be populated with answers so when I reload the page `<span>
About both equaly<input name="question1" value="both" checked="" type="radio">
</span>`. it shouldn't have been checked since I didn't select anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove the `checked` attribute from all the checkboxes unless there is ONE that you want to be pre-selected and in that case add it to just that ONE.

There is no need to loop through the radio buttons to see which was checked. Just use the `:checked` pseudo-class. Change this:

```
    $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
        console.log("this ",this);
        if($(this).attr("checked")){
            values[this.name] = {answer : $(this).val()};
        }

    })
```

to this:

```
   var checkedRad = $("input[type='radio']:checked");
   values[this.name] = {answer : checkRad.value};
```

or, if you don't need a reference to the checked radio button after getting its value::

```
   values[this.name] = {answer : $("input[type='radio']:checked")};
```

```js
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", function(e){

        console.log($("input[type='radio']:checked").val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question1">
  <label> Do you shop mostly on-line or at physical stores? </label>
    <div class="radioButtons">
      <span>
       Mostly on-line stores
       <input name="question1" value="on-line" type="radio">
      </span>
      <span>
        mostly physical stores
        <input name="question1" value="physical" type="radio">
      </span>
      <span>
        About both equaly
        <input name="question1" value="both" type="radio">
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope this works because it looked like my problem was that checked attribute for the radio button wasn't being set when the user clicks the radio button. aren't I supposed to see a checked attribute get added in firebug when the radio button is clicked? and this looks like it checks which one has the checked attribute in the query query.

Comment: Because RadioButtons are mutually exclusive (because they all have the same `name`) only one can ever be selected and that is the only one that will be "attached" to the checked value. The CSS `:checked` pseudo-class isn't looking for the `checked` attribute. It's looking for the radio button (can be used with checkboxes as well) that is in the checked state.

Comment: Thanks: this seamed to work for me        `$(".radioButtons").each(function(){
                var checkRad = $(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked");
                values[checkRad.attr("name")] = {answer : checkRad.val()};
            });` because it didnt seam to get the other set of radio buttons

Comment: You don't need the `each` loop at all. Just query for the radio button that is checked. Your solution may work but it is way overkill. You can just write the single last line in my answer instead of all that.

Comment: I tried your way but it only got the first set of radio buttons but when I did the `each` it got all the sets that are in each `radioButtons` div. You still say I didn't need to do the `.each`? I only tried it once.

Comment: @jackblank I think you are missing the point here. There is no need for looping through a set of radio buttons to get the value of the one that has been checked. Just used the `:checked` pseudo-class on your selector and you will immediately get the single radio button that is currently selected. Look at my updated answer's code snippet for an example. One line of code is all you need - no `.each()`.